# Get the user's email address from Azure AD via OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to authenticate users to my site with their Office 365 accounts, so I have been following the guidance on using the OWIN OpenID Connect middleware to add authentication and successfully managed to authenticate and retrieve their profile.

I am now trying to get the email address of the user (so I can populate their system account with their contact details), but I can't seem to get an email claim back. I have tried making a request using the scope `openid profile email`, but the claim-set does not contain any mail information.

Is there a way to get the email of a user from Azure AD via the OpenID Connect endpoint?

Comment: FWIW: my Azure AD account that is connected to my Live ID returns the "mail" claim regardless of the requested `scope` so I guess it is a server side configuration (or limitation).

Comment: @HansZ. Could you share the permissions your client application has been granted? Mine only has **Enable sign-on and read users profiles**

Comment: Mine has the exact same: only `Enable sign-on and read users' profiles` enabled, in the section `permissions to other applications`, for the entry `Windows Azure Active Directory`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I struggled with the same problem for a few days before arriving at a solution. In answer to your question: yes, you should be able to get the e-mail address back in your claims as long as you:

1. Include the `profile` or `email` scope in your request, and
2. Configure your application in the Azure Portal Active Directory section to include *Sign in and read user profile* under *Delegated Permissions*.

Note that the e-mail address may not be returned in an `email` claim: in my case (once I got it working) it's coming back in a `name` claim.

However, not getting the e-mail address back *at all* could be caused by one of the following issues:

#### No e-mail address associated with the Azure AD account

As per this guide to [Scopes, permissions, and consent in the Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-scopes#openid-connect-scopes), even if you include the `email` scope you may not get an e-mail address back:

> The `email` claim is included in a token only if an email address is associated with the user account, which is not always the case. If it uses the `email` scope, your app should be prepared to handle a case in which the `email` claim does not exist in the token.

If you're getting other profile-related claims back (like `given_name` and `family_name`), this might be the problem.

#### Claims discarded by middleware

This was the cause for me. I wasn't getting *any* profile-related claims back (first name, last name, username, e-mail, etc.).

In my case, the identity-handling stack looks like this:

- [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)
- [IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity)
- A custom Couchbase storage provider based on [couchbase-aspnet-identity](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-aspnet-identity)

The problem was in the IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity `AspNetIdentityUserService` class: the [`InstantiateNewUserFromExternalProviderAsync()` method looks like this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity/blob/2.0.0/source/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.cs#L300):

```
protected virtual Task<TUser> InstantiateNewUserFromExternalProviderAsync(
    string provider,
    string providerId,
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    var user = new TUser() { UserName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") };
    return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

Note it passes in a claims collection then ignores it. My solution was to create a class derived from this and override the method to something like this:

```
protected override Task<TUser> InstantiateNewUserFromExternalProviderAsync(
    string provider,
    string providerId,
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    var user = new TUser
    {
        UserName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
        Claims = claims
    };
    return Task.FromResult(user);
}
```

I don't know exactly what middleware components you're using, but it's easy to see the raw claims returned from your external provider; that'll at least tell you they're coming back OK and that the problem is somewhere in your middleware. Just add a `Notifications` property to your `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` object, like this:

```
// Configure Azure AD as a provider
var azureAdOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = Constants.Azure.AuthenticationType,
    Caption = Resources.AzureSignInCaption,
    Scope = Constants.Azure.Scopes,
    ClientId = Config.Azure.ClientId,
    Authority = Constants.Azure.AuthenticationRootUri,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Config.Identity.RedirectUri,
    RedirectUri = Config.Azure.PostSignInRedirectUri,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    },
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
        {
            // Log all the claims returned by Azure AD
            var claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                Log.Debug("{0} = {1}", claim.Type, claim.Value);
            }
            return null;
        }
    },
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType // this MUST come after TokenValidationParameters
};

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(azureAdOptions);
```

#### See also

- [This article by Scott Brady](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-3) contains a section on Claims Transformation which may be useful if neither of the above fixes it.
- [This discussion on the IdentityServer3 GitHub account](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/821) was a huge help to me, especially [this response](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/821#issuecomment-71491969).

Comment: I'm also using IdentityServer(4), but I don't think it's the problem; the id_token coming from AzureAD doesn't include profile-related claims, even before it was processed by IdentityServer. I specified `openid profile email` as the scopes. The AAD user has an associated email. Not that there's a `preferred_username` claim which contains the email, but using this seems fragile.

Comment: There's a missing hyphen above - for "Sign in"; it should be 'Sign-in and read user profile' - and it's within the (Microsoft Graph) 'User permissions' section:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions.

In relation specifically to OIDC, the 'email' permission instead might possibly be a better choice:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-43

Answer (score 11):

I was struggling with the same issue for days...  I was getting the email address from users with personal Microsoft accounts but not for those with company Microsoft accounts.

For personal accounts, the email address is returned in an `email` field like one would expect.

For company accounts, the email address is returned in a `preferred_username` field.

Keeping my fingers crossed that there isn't another Microsoft variation that I haven't discovered yet...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't rely on `preferred_username` to be a valid (or immutable) email, company account or not. See the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference
> It could be a ... phone number, or a generic username without a specified format.

Answer (score 3):

Is it an option for you to pass &resource=https://graph.windows.net in the sign-in request to the authorization endpoint, then query the Azure AD Graph API for the authenticated organizational user's Office 365 email address? For example, GET https://graph.windows.net/me/mail?api-version=1.5

For additional reference, see the WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet code sample on the AzureADSamples GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't actually deliver the mail claims via the OpenID Connect token, but I appreciate it is a viable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for 2019: `email` claim is an optional claim that might be not included in the request ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims))

> For managed users (those inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim or, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope.

You have to update the manifest file in the Azure Portal to include optional claim, like so:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
}
```

This answer was partially inspired by [this blog post](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-ad-custom-attributes-and-optional-claims-from-an-asp-dot-net-application/).

Comment: This was a great clue for me. While not providing the complete answer, I was able to track my problem back to the Azure AD, App Registration in the Azure Portal where I added email as an optional parameter.

Comment: @GlennMoseley would you mind to expand on that? What did you do to fix the issue with email? I'm facing it right now

Comment: @Andrey Hi Andrey, sorry it's been a while. I doubt you are still facing this issue but I'll add my solution in case you are, or for any further follow ups. In the Azure portal for the AD  tenant you are configured against. If you go to App registrations, select the App name you want to configure and then select Token configuration. You can add an optional parameter of email. This requires OpenID connect scopes to also be configures.

Answer (score 1):

in the same situation I ended up with a very simple code that return all the user claims accesible after login (including email)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected string GetCurrentUserIDFromClaims()
        {
            return User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        }

        protected List<string> AllClaimsFromAzure()
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity);
            return claimsIdentity.Claims.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        }

        protected string GetCurrentEmailFromAzureClaims()
        {
            return AllClaimsFromAzure()[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> so I can populate their system account with their contact details

Looks like you can't reliably obtain an email address from AAD claims.

Here are some of the claims that you may think you can use for this purpose and their documentation (copied from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-token-claims-reference)), emphasis mine.

| Claim | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `preferred_username` | The primary username that represents the user. It could be an email address, **phone number, or a generic username** without a specified format. Its value is mutable and might change over time. Since it's mutable, this value **can't be used to make authorization decisions**. It can be used for username hints and in human-readable UI as a username. The `profile` scope is required to receive this claim. Present only in v2.0 tokens. |
| `name` | The `name` claim provides a human-readable value that identifies the subject of the token. The value isn't guaranteed to be unique, it can be changed, and **should be used only for display purposes**. The `profile` scope is required to receive this claim. |
| `email` | Present by default for guest accounts that have an email address. Your app can request the email claim for managed users (from the same tenant as the resource) using the `email` optional claim. This value isn't guaranteed to be correct and is mutable over time. **Never use it for authorization or to save data for a user**. If you require an addressable email address in your app, request this data from the user directly by using this claim as a suggestion or prefill in your UX. On the v2.0 endpoint, your app can also request the `email` OpenID Connect scope - you don't need to request both the optional claim and the scope to get the claim. |

So I guess your best bet is to follow the advice of the doc on the `email` claim and show a registration form to the user, on which the field "Email" is pre-filled with the value of `preferred_username` or `email`. The user should confirm that this value actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `upn` value from the user's claims:

```
var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
string email = userClaims?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn)?.Value;
```