# How can I get the standard OpenID connect claims when using Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory B2C?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

We are developing an ASP.NET core 2.2 web application by using [IdentityServer 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) as a gateway to other identity providers following the [federation gateway architecture](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/federation_gateway.html).

The application we are developing is the actual identity provider web application which is, as explained above, just a gateway to some configured upstream identity providers.

The user basically configures his preferred upstream identity providers and our application takes care of configuring IdentityServer4 so that the configured providers are used as external identity providers for identity server itself.

The requirement for the application user is that each configured provider must be compliant with the OpenID connect protocol. Each upstream provider is in fact registered with identity server 4 by using the [ASP.NET core authentication handler for OpenID connect](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src).

During the development phase we are testing the application by using [Azure active directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) and our company's instance of [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) as test upstream identity providers.

We ask for 3 different scopes during the authentication: `openid`, `profile` and `email`.

We do so because the only user claims that we need from the external provider are `sub` (provided by the `openid` scope), `given_name` and `family_name` (provided by the `profile` scope) and `email` (provided by the `email` scope). **Notice that the `email` claim is really important for us, because we want to use it as the primary key by which identifying the system users** (this is relevant for the Azure Active Directory B2C issue explained below).

These are [standard open id connect scopes and claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) so we expected to find them easily in our test providers. Unfortunately the reality is different and neither Azure Active Directory nor Azure Active Directory B2C send 
all of these claims.

What we actually get are the following claims:

- `sub`, `name` and `email` from Azure active directory (`given_name` and `family_name` are missing)
- `sub`, `emails`, `given_name` and `family_name` from Azure active directory B2C (notice that `emails` is not a standard claim and from the Azure portal it is classified as **StringCollection**, so it seems possible to get multiple emails for a user which is not what we want).

My questions are basically the followings:

- is it possible to get the standard OpenID connect `sub`, `email`, `given_name`, and `family_name` claims from both Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory B2C ? Is it just a matter of configuring them properly ?
- is it possible to assume that **any** identity provider declaring of being compliant with OpenID connect is able to provide us with these four claims ? **We would like to avoid cluttering our code base of fallback logic to handle the 
  subtle specificity of different providers**

Thanks for helping !

Comment: As far as AAD goes, have you checked if the App Registration is delegated User.Read (Sign and read user profile) permission? This SO question might be of help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983694/get-the-users-email-address-from-azure-ad-via-openid-connect

Comment: @ayls I have checked. I have registered a test application under the company's AAD, which is basically the application we are developing executed on localhost. This application has been granted the permission "Sign in and read user profile" for my own user on the company's AAD. When I run the app on localhost I log in with my user, but I'm not able to get the claims given_name and family_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a claims that are marked as `OPTIONAL` by the OpenID Connect Standard.

As far as it concerns Azure AD (not B2C), here is the doc:

- [Tokens and claims in Microsoft Identity Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#claims-in-an-id_token) (no given_name & family_name)
- Regarding `given_name`, `family_name`, `email` check the [optional claims in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) doc in order to include these in your `id_token`.

And for B2C, hmm, there is really no documentation about that, or I am having issues finding it. [This is a general B2C tokens reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens). But just go to your `user_flow` and define the requested claims for the application (relying party):

[image]

There is a general challenge how you issue an e-mail claim in a B2C context. Because you may have a local user, or a social user (which includes the Azure AD user federated over B2C in your case) or even a remote user (more complex scenarios with custom flows). So you do not have really have a source of truth for the e-mail.

Given name and family name are so called `self asserted` - the end user provides the info and you (B2C) just save it to the profile. So your application is getting information provided by the user. It may be anything.

You are certainly able to create a custom claim and name it `email` instead of `emails` in B2C. But you have to ultimately decide which will be source for this claim. You can achieve that goal using [custom flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).

I would generally also argue against e-mail being primary key or even a match for something. There are enough circumstances, especially within a corporation when an employee e-mail may and will change. And your application shall not rely on the fact that e-mail is immutable property of a user profile.

With this, I believe I answered only question one.

As for the latter:

> is it possible to assume that any identity provider declaring of being
>   compliant with OpenID connect is able to provide us with these four
>   claims ?

Do not forget that the claims you refer to are marked `OPTIONAL` in [the OpenID Connect specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims). That means that an Identity provider does not have to implement these in order to be OpenID Connect compliant. More specifically, the documentation states:

> Claims requested by the following scopes are treated by Authorization
>   Servers as Voluntary Claims.

But yes - Azure Active Directory provides all of them - with the configuration for the optional claims. And B2C also provides them - with more complex workaround for the `email` claim.

Comment: thanks a lot very helpful. I'm quite new to this topic so I didn't catch that the claims I asked about are considered optional by the specification. So, the only user claim that we can always expect to receive is the `sub` claim (the unique identifier of the user in the identity provider), right ?